# If the user has the camera settings to store location data, but the phones location is off, would the location be stored?

Tags: android, geolocation

I need photos uploaded to my app to be geotagged.
My question is as follows:
Assume the user's camera settings are set to store location data, but the phone location is currently off.
Would the phone retrieve the location to take the photo? Or does the setting to keep location data is only valid when the whole phone's location is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assume the user's camera settings are set to store location data

There are hundreds, if not thousands, of camera apps available for Android. This includes both pre-installed and user-installed apps. None have to support geo-tagging.

> Would the phone retrieve the location to take the photo?

No, barring some bug in the device firmware.

> Or does the setting to keep location data is only valid when the whole phone's location is on?

If a camera app offers geo-tagging, that is subject to the same limitations of any other app. If the user has disabled locations for the device, that will affect all apps, including any camera apps.